# Form not using Ajax, posting directly to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am posting a form to a php file using ajax but for some reason which I can't figure out, it is not using ajax but directly posting to php.

My form:

```
  <form id="editform" name="editform" action="ajaxeditform.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="aid" id="aid" readonly class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"/>
      <input type="text" name="number" id="tailnumber" readonly class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"/>
      <input type="text" name="type" id="type" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="e.g. C172" />
      <input type="text" name="colormarkings" id="colormarkings" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update info</button></div>
  </form>
```

My jquery:

```
 $('#editform').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
    })
    .success(function(response) {
        // remove all errors
        $('input').removeClass('error').next('.errormessage').html('');

        if(!response.errors && response.result) {

                new PNotify({
                            title: 'Success',
                            text: 'Info updated successfully',
                            type: 'success'
                        });

        } else {

            $.each(response.errors, function( index, value) {
                // add error classes
                $('input[name*='+index+']').addClass('error').after('<div class="errormessage">'+value+'</div>')
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Form opening tag is not proper. Is it typo?

Comment: Check console for error....

Comment: Is the submit event bound? I guess no and surely because you are trying to set it before element is available in DOM

Comment: submit button always posts form. Use  <input type="button" ...

Comment: @Mehmet, `e.preventDefault();` is there to prevent that..

Comment: @Mehmet this is not true while use preventDefault

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have no errors in my console.

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't have any elements that are added dynamically

Comment: But if you put an console.log() (or alert() to block script) at top of submit event handler, is it outputting anything??? Are you setting snippet in head section? In document ready handler? Or what?

Comment: Use error atttribute of $.ajax to check if there is any post error on ajax request

Comment: It's your javascript code inside of `$( document ).ready()`?

Comment: @A.Wolff If i use console.log() it doesn't show anything, which i'm assuming means that that function isn't even being called.

Comment: @DavidRosa No, it is not.

Comment: @Bruno Then you should

Comment: So ya, event isn't bound surely because **you are trying to set it before element is available in DOM**...

Comment: Try  `$(function(){
 $('#editform').on('submit', function(e){
  // your code that as shown in the question
 });
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes:-

**`Form opening tag is not proper`, change like below:-**

`<form id="editform" name="editform" action="ajaxeditform.php" method="post">`

**try to change your jquery code first line like below:-**

`$('Form#editform').on('submit', function(e){`  OR `$('.btn-success').click(function(e){`

**Add jquery library also (check that it is added or not?). for example add this code before `jQuery` code:-**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

**add `$(document).ready(function(){` in your code.like below:-**

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  ........ //your code
});
```

Comment: 1. `Form` tag was a typo 2. How does this make any difference ? 3. There are no errors in the console as per OP..

Comment: If i use 2, can i still use the $(this).attr method? My jquery is running fine because all my other jquery functions run fine on the page.

Comment: @Bruno We told you to wrap it in document ready handler, isn't fixing it for you???

Comment: Number 4 solved my issue! I always thought that it was not necessary to have your functions inside the document ready function but as @david-rosa pointed out that was the issue. Thank you all!

Comment: @Bruno welcome, and my appreciation too for all others who pointed the same issue.